# SwiftUI binding boolean if statement (Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected condition type 'Bool')

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to conditionally show a View (not using .sheet) and using a binding boolean returns the error above in the title. If I use `self.menuactivated`, no view will be presented upon the @State variable toggle. Is there a way around this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var menuActivated  = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ... // code
        }
        if $menuActivated {
            menuView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `$` here.. Just use `if menuActivated { }`

Comment: `if menuActivated` is correct.  If you aren't seeing the menu then you have a problem with your layout.  Set `menuActivated` to `true` by default and make sure it is visible

Comment: @NewDev - removing $ changes nothing

Comment: @Paulw11 - Tried using that and also using .position(x: 0, y:0) to check if the view would show and it was nowhere to be seen.

Comment: If you removed `if`, and just kept `menuView`, would it display the view the way you want?

Comment: Right, so you have a problem with your view layout, not the boolean test.  Your menu appears to be outside the `NavigationView` - the code you have shown isn't valid. You would need an enclosing `VStack` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around it. Embedded the `NavigationView` in a `VStack` and added the `menuView` to the end of it.

```
struct ContentView: View {        
@State private var menuActivated  = false

        var body: some View {
            ZStack {

                NavigationView {
                ... // view code        
                }
                if menuActivated {
                    menuView()
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this was the intention (menu will be shown over NavigationView on toggle)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var menuActivated  = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           NavigationView {
            ... // code
           }
           if menuActivated {
              menuView()
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are looking for condition based view

```
func getView() -> AnyView {
    return AnyView(
        //any business logic and view  
    )
}
```

and use it like

```
self.getView()
```